# R Histogram multiple color zones

Tags: r, histogram

I tried looking around to see how I can color code a generic histogram based on its range and I couldnt seem to find one on stack overflow. Im essentially trying to color code the two extreme ends of a histogram different colors. Is there a way to do so?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `cut`?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000, 11, 5))

dat |> 
  mutate(z = cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, 5, 15, +Inf))) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x, fill = z)) +
  geom_histogram()
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way for me to specify colors for each part?

Comment: scale_fill_discrete(type = c("orange", "grey", "blue")), also mutate isn't necessary you can pass the cut function to the fill argument